# Netbeans IDE 7.2.1: How to add the c++ boost library

Tags: c++, boost, netbeans

For my next assignment I require threading in C++ and have read that the boost library for threading works fairly well.  I've never added a custom library to Netbeans and was hoping someone could provide me some steps to follow in order to allow me to #include it and use it in my class.

So far I've downloaded the following:
Boost library from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.52.0/
(Not sure if it matters where I extract this too.. I'm assuming I need to set NetBeans to point at it somewhere within the properties of my package?)

NetBeans 7.2.1 C/C++ Installer for Windows from here: http://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=cpp

Compiling with: MinGW

Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linking library:

> Project -> properties -> Linker ->Libraries -> Add option -> Other ->
>   -l%libname%

Path to libraries:

> Project -> properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories

Includes:

> Project -> properties -> C++ Compiler -> Include Directories ->
>   %paths_to_boost%

Comment: The 'Path to libraries' and 'Includes' steps seemed to have worked but after I link the library it won't compile for me.

Returns with: 
c:\minGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -l%thread%
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: try also add same library path to runtime library path