# Boost in Netbeans 7.1.1

Tags: c++, windows, boost, netbeans, shared-libraries

Trying to run the following:

```
        #include<iostream>
        #include<boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

        namespace bfs=boost::filesystem;
        int main()
        {
        bfs::path p("second.cpp");
        if(bfs::exists(p))
        std::cout<<p.leaf()<<std::endl;
        }
```

I got some errors in cygwin so I decided to try out netbeans, and used the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291582/netbeans-ide-7-2-1-how-to-add-the-c-boost-library) as a guide. I added all links and the following for filesystem `Project -> properties -> Linker ->Libraries -> Add option -> Other -> -lfile_system` as noted [here](http://tabreziqbal.wordpress.com/2006/03/16/how-to-test-c-boost-installation/). I have run a separate test using `#include<boost/any.hpp>` so I am not currently doubting that my boost is not installed correclty.

It seems weird to me that it is "file_system", so I also tried "filesystem" but to no avail.

When i hold `Ctrl` and click on `#include<boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>` my netbeans brings up my `operations.hpp` file so it seems okay (linked properly internally that it can "see" what I want it to see).

---

The solution to installing boost came in the following form:
1 - If you have any path variables that are being used for Visual Studio you should temporarily change the variable during installation. [This is a good guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519). Once that is done, this is one step completed.

2 - Download and install MinGW. This is a very easy process and you can find the installer files [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW).

Once you have done these things (if you are in the same situation as me), you will now be able to properly install boost.

Horay!

Comment: `-lfile_system` is wrong. Usually, it is `-lboost_filesystem` or `-lboost_filesystem-mt`, check your lib directory. You might also need `-lboost_system`.

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: Jesse - tried those. Not working still.

Comment: Did you read the error message? **Boost.Filesystem V3 and later requires std::wstring support.** Does your standard library provide std::wstring?

Comment: You should determine the answer to the question that @Sam posted. Make sure you are using gcc4-g++ (rather than gcc-g++), and also the latest libstdc++. You could try compiling a very simple test:
`#include <string>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   std::wstring w;
   return 0;
}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29778/discussion-between-moskito-x-and-jason-m)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Using Boost with cygwin step by step

**Create a new Project**

[image]

*It is better to take the names given here in this tutorial **exactly**. Later ask: It does not work, can then be easier to find.*

**I do not think I need to mention all `T:\` must of course be replaced with your drive.**

Project Name : `Boost-cyg-Test`

[image]

Now your Project should look like

[image]

Open main.cpp
Overwrite the generated code with the following. We want to that, first of all everything works without error.

Therefore, please do not use your own special code.
It is difficult to find a fault. Then told after several ask, to get:
*I have used my own code*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
  {
    path p("second.cpp");
      if (exists(p)) { std::cout<<p.leaf()<<std::endl; }
  }
```

*In this section we assume that "boost" is already compiled.*

goto Tools -> Options

Your C++ Code Assistance options should look something like this.

[image]

If this is not so, we should let Netbeans create that for us.

[image]

Add New Tool Collection

[image]

After we have completed this dialog with OK, we should find the settings shown above. ( C++ Code Assistance options).

**Copy all libs into the right place**

Let's create a new folder 'boost'.

[image]

With a search tool, search in your compiled Boost folder for `*.a`
My `Boost` is compiled with the `shared option` so we find :

[image]

For our short App. we need only 2 files.

```
libboost_filesystem-gcc45-mt-d-1_53.dll.a
libboost_system-gcc45-mt-d-1_53.dll.a
```

But if we're at it to copy two files, we can copy all files.
So mark all found `.a` files and copy them into the directory just created
`T:\cygwin\lib\boost` .

Now we do the same with our `.dll` files.
Mark all `.dll` files and copy it in your `?:\cygwin\bin` directory.
If you only have compiled static librarys, you can skip this point.

[image]

Now it's time to modify our project settings.
As you can see i put my source Boost folder into cygwin

[image]

and

[image]

As we have already noted above, we need two `.a` files.
with Add Library navigate to `T:\cygwin\lib\boost` and select

```
libboost_filesystem-gcc45-mt-d-1_53.dll.a
libboost_system-gcc45-mt-d-1_53.dll.a
```

Now you'll notice that this name was shortened by netbeans to:

```
boost_filesystem-gcc45-mt-d-1_53.dll
boost_system-gcc45-mt-d-1_53.dll
```

[image]

This is somewhat confusing. It looks as if a `.dll` is standing here. But it is really a `.a` file.

Set a breakpoint in main.cpp. Now we start debug.

[image]

I have marked the important part, the two libs, with an arrow.
All libs are found and after make has finished, stops at the breakpoint.

The output:

[image]

### Build Boost for Cygwin

For all who want to create boost with shared library itself.

[Download boost_1_53_0.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/?source=directory)

Create a folder in your ?:\cygwin directory.
`boost_1_53_0`

[image]

Extract the zip file into that directory.
It should look like:

[image]

open a cmd window, cd to `boost_1_53_0` directory.
To have a clean build we need a PATH that have only the `cygwin home` and `bin`.
In the cmd type.

```
SET PATH=T:\cygwin;T:\cygwin\bin
```

and test the path.

```
PATH
```

[image]

Type

```
bootstrap.bat
```

[image]

Type

```
.\b2 --build-dir=T:\boost-cyg toolset=gcc variant=debug link=shared runtime-link=shared
```

After some time the build is finished.
Now you have the same environment that we have used in the tutorial.

If you get a Error : `gcc not found`
copy (not rename) in `?:\cygwin\bin` folder, for example : (names may differ).
`i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-4.5.3.exe` to `gcc.exe`
and
`i686-pc-cygwin-g++-4.exe` to `g++.exe`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i did that. ok new issue: i don't have libboost_(etc).dll, but i have cygboost_(etc).dll that being said i do not have filesystem. this seems odd. i am trying your boost installation instructions now to see if this solves the problem.

Comment: when I run the cmd you write above I get the error that will be posted above as a screenshot (appended to my question)

Comment: cygwin make.exe here [make-cyg.zip](http://www.moskito-x.de/stack/files/make-cyg.zip) .

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste the error you get when compiling ?
I am not used to compile programs in a Windows environment, but I think as Jesse Good suggested in a comment that you have a linker error.

You may solve it by using `-lboost_filesystem` instead of `lfile_system`.

To find out how your libs are called, you get the name of your lib (on my unix environment I have libboost_filesystem.so), strip the "lib" prefix and the ".so" or ".a" suffix (must be different in a Windows environment).

Comment: where would these libboost_filesystem.so files be found? i do not see these in my ~/usr/include/   where exactly would they be?

Comment: The libs (used by the linker) are located in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib. The headers (those you include with #include) are located in /usr/include or /usr/local/include

Answer (score 0):

if your boost installation is correct and you are sure about it then for `Unable to resolve identifier` try **Code Assistance->Reparse Project** from context menu of the project. It tries to recover broken code model by reparsing project from scratch. if that didn't workout try closing IDE and removing code model cache.

p.s. do you have compilation errors?